# Selecting best combination of worker set that are capable to perform given set of tasks

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, np-hard

I have a set of workers W1, W2... Wn each with different capabilities/skillsets. I have a set of tasks T1, T2... Tn.

- T1 can be performed by W1 and W2
- T2 can be performed by W1
- T3 can be performed by W1, W2, W3
- T4 can be performed by W2

The tasks T1, T2, T3 and T4 HAVE to be done sequentially and it is fine if some workers are IDLE. In this case, the best worker set combination that are capable of performing all the tasks is {W1 and W2}. Is there an algorithm that can identify such a best fit combination?

I have looked into [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). By representing the problem as a 2D matrix with Tasks as Rows and Workers as Columns:

1   1   1   0
1   0   1   1
0   0   1   0

Identifying the minimal number of rows so that the union of those subsets is everything, i.e. so that all columns are represented is a NP hard problem. My question is if it really is a Set Cover problem or am I looking at it in the wrong direction? Are there other algorithms that help finding near-optimal solutions to these problems?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Sorry, I have edited the question and included my research on the problem so far.

Comment: You need to define "best".  Is it the smallest possible set?